# Connecting GeoJSON on GeoServer to Carto

Tags: geoserver, geojson, carto

GeoServer can output GeoJSON via WFS.

Carto can read GeoJSON via URL.

Should it then be possible to connect a GeoJSON layer in Carto from a GeoServer WFS?

I'm trying this setup, but I'm getting a cryptic "unknown error" in Carto when trying to connect to GeoJSON output.

If I save the same output to file and upload it to Carto, it loads fine. So the problem seems to be in the connection rather than the data.

[Edit] Here is a link to the relevant GeoJSON: [GeoJSON output from GeoServer](http://194.103.190.7:8080/geoserver/rs/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=rs:vardcentraler&maxFeatures=500&outputFormat=application%2Fjson)

Comment: what happens if you save the WFS output as a file and load that to carto? should tell you if the formats are compatible at least

Comment: I tried this (saving the GeoServer GeoJSON to file and uploading it), and it worked. So I guess the format works.

Comment: please add this information to the question

Comment: if this is an Open Source installation of CARTO then you should check the importer logs. If you are using carto.com then you can add to your question the ID of the import so we can take a look here. We have positive feedback of that specific use case so it should work.

Comment: On the other hand, if you provide a valid URL WFS request we can do also a quick check here

Comment: @JorgeSanz I've edited my question to include the link.

Comment: If you check your console you'll see CARTO is not accepting imports from urls like yours. I think it's because of using an IP.

`{"errors":{"imports":"Invalid URL, cannot connect dataset: ..."}}`

Comment: @JorgeSanz Ah, if set up a proper DNS I'll try again and get back here.

Comment: @JorgeSanz I now connect to the server via a DNS, the new adress is: http://geodata.skane.se:8080/geoserver/rs/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=rs:vardcentraler&outputFormat=json, and I'm still getting an error.

Comment: Sorry but CARTO valid ports are only 21, 80 and 443. Any other ports will not be accepted by the [url validation process](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/lib/carto/url_validator.rb#L7).